# Scheme replacement problems

Tags: scheme, racket

This code replaces first person words with second person words and vice versa.  However, it goes through each pair for each word in the phrase, so sometimes it will change back.

Here is the code:

```
(define (replace pattern replacement lst replacement-pairs)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
    ((equal? (car lst) pattern)
       (cons replacement
             (many-replace (cdr replacement-pairs) (cdr lst))))
    (else (cons (car lst)
          (many-replace (cdr replacement-pairs) (cdr lst))))))

(define (many-replace replacement-pairs lst)
  (cond ((null? replacement-pairs) lst)
     (else (let ((pat-rep (car replacement-pairs)))
        (replace (car pat-rep)
                 (cadr pat-rep)
                 (many-replace (cdr replacement-pairs)
                 lst) replacement-pairs)))))

(define (change-person phrase)
  (many-replace '((i you) (me you) (am are) (my your) (are am) (you i) (your my))
            phrase))
```

For example if I entered

```
(change-person '(you are not being very helpful to me))
```

it would change you to i but then back to you.  How do I fix this?

Comment: There's no need for the mutual recursion here, and that's being handled inconsistently. For example, in `replace` you're advancing over the replacement pairs when a match is found in the input list - that doesn't make sense. It's simpler to start over from the beginning than to try to fix this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedures `replace` and  `many-replace` are overly complicated, and the mutual recursion is not doing what you think. If we simplify those procedures and make sure that only a single pass is performed over the input list, we can get a correct answer:

```
(define (replace replacement-pairs pattern)
  (cond ((null? replacement-pairs)
         pattern)
        ((equal? (caar replacement-pairs) pattern)
         (cadar replacement-pairs))
        (else
         (replace (cdr replacement-pairs) pattern))))

(define (many-replace replacement-pairs lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (replace replacement-pairs (car lst))
            (many-replace replacement-pairs (cdr lst)))))
```

The keen eye will notice that the previous procedures can be expressed in a succinct way by using some higher-order procedures. A more idiomatic solution could look like this:

```
(define (replace replacement-pairs pattern)
  (cond ((assoc pattern replacement-pairs) => cadr)
        (else pattern)))

(define (many-replace replacement-pairs lst)
  (map (curry replace replacement-pairs) lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(change-person '(you are not being very helpful to me))
=> '(i am not being very helpful to you)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a slightly easier solution:

```
(define (many-replace pattern phrase)
  (let loop ((phrase phrase) (result '()))
    (if (empty? phrase) (reverse result)
        (let* ((c (car phrase)) (a (assoc c pattern)))
          (if a
              (loop (cdr phrase) (cons (cadr a) result))
              (loop (cdr phrase) (cons c result)))))))

(change-person '(you are not being very helpful to me))
=> '(i am not being very helpful to you)
```